# IOS 7.1.2 app closes at presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am new to Xcode and Objective-C and I apologize for this noob question but I need help. I am using storyboard and have a second view controller used for settings and game over screens. This appears to work fine in IOS 8 and above but the app just closes in IOS 7.1.2 when this code is executed.

```
// This View Controller will provide a means of checking Game Center standings/ achievements
- (IBAction)settingsVC:(id)sender {

    IOSSettingsViewController *vc = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IOSSettingsViewController"];
    vc.alphaFromVC1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

// RESET the START BUTTON
    [self.startButton setEnabled:YES];
    return;
}
```

The app closes without bring up the second (settings) view controller. Can anyone suggest what is wrong? Again it works fine in IOS 8. Thanks so much for steering me in the right direction.

Here is a crash log from one of my beta testers.

```
{"bundleID":"org.technologyministries.SpokenCatch52","app_name":"Catch52","bug_type":"109","name":"Catch52","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)","version":"1.1 (1.0)"}
Incident Identifier: F830A1C1-9D6E-4564-BBAA-A56C073483CA
CrashReporter Key:   406fb56ed5a3dd1731840affeba0206cba7b353e
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             Catch52 [465]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/FA761024-4026-4EB1-AF58-B6D530C010A1/Catch52.app/Catch52
Identifier:          org.technologyministries.SpokenCatch52
Version:             1.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-09 14:38:33.386 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1845f7100 0x190b001fc 0x1845fbdb4 0x1845f9ae0 0x18451978c 0x100079768 0x1875c0658 0x1875c03dc 0x18763f17c 0x18763f0b4 0x1876b75fc 0x1876b5a84 0x102469064 0x10008ee48 0x1910d8014 0x1910d7fd4 0x1910ddea8 0x1910d7fd4 0x1910d9b90 0x1910db180 0x1845b6ddc 0x1845b511c 0x1844f5dd0 0x18a1ddc0c 0x187626fc4 0x100093268 0x1910f3aa0)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911ee58c 0x1911d4000 + 107916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000191182804 0x191120000 + 403460
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001903a8990 0x1903a8000 + 2448
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001903c5c28 0x1903a8000 + 121896
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190b004d0 0x190af8000 + 34000
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001903c3164 0x1903a8000 + 110948
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001903c2a7c 0x1903a8000 + 109180
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190b00314 0x190af8000 + 33556
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845fbdb0 0x1844ec000 + 1113520
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845f9adc 0x1844ec000 + 1104604
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184519788 0x1844ec000 + 186248
11  Catch52                         0x0000000100079764 0x100074000 + 22372
12  UIKit                           0x00000001875c0654 0x1875ac000 + 83540
13  UIKit                           0x00000001875c03d8 0x1875ac000 + 82904
14  UIKit                           0x000000018763f178 0x1875ac000 + 602488
15  UIKit                           0x000000018763f0b0 0x1875ac000 + 602288
16  UIKit                           0x00000001876b75f8 0x1875ac000 + 1095160
17  UIKit                           0x00000001876b5a80 0x1875ac000 + 1088128
18  UIKit                           0x0000000102469060 0x10242c000 + 249952
19  Catch52                         0x000000010008ee44 0x100074000 + 110148
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d8010 0x1910d4000 + 16400
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d7fd0 0x1910d4000 + 16336
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910ddea4 0x1910d4000 + 40612
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d7fd0 0x1910d4000 + 16336
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d9b8c 0x1910d4000 + 23436
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910db17c 0x1910d4000 + 29052
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6dd8 0x1844ec000 + 830936
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b5118 0x1844ec000 + 823576
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
29  GraphicsServices                0x000000018a1ddc08 0x18a1d0000 + 56328
30  UIKit                           0x0000000187626fc0 0x1875ac000 + 503744
31  Catch52                         0x0000000100093264 0x100074000 + 127588
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001910f3a9c 0x1910f0000 + 15004

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5aa8 0x1911d4000 + 6824
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910d9998 0x1910d4000 + 22936

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911eee74 0x1911d4000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d548 0x19126c000 + 5448

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5ca0 0x1911d4000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6d20 0x1844ec000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4eb0 0x1844ec000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
4   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001833615ec 0x183350000 + 71148
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x000000018335601c 0x183350000 + 24604
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fe18 0x19126c000 + 15896
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fd70 0x19126c000 + 15728
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d550 0x19126c000 + 5456

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5ca0 0x1911d4000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6d20 0x1844ec000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4eb0 0x1844ec000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
4   Foundation                      0x00000001850912c0 0x185080000 + 70336
5   libAXSpeechManager.dylib        0x000000018fe3fe94 0x18fe3c000 + 16020
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185178408 0x185080000 + 1016840
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fe18 0x19126c000 + 15896
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fd70 0x19126c000 + 15728
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d550 0x19126c000 + 5456

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5ca0 0x1911d4000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6d20 0x1844ec000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4eb0 0x1844ec000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
4   TextToSpeech                    0x000000018d3e0284 0x18d3d8000 + 33412
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fe18 0x19126c000 + 15896
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fd70 0x19126c000 + 15728
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d550 0x19126c000 + 5456

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5ca0 0x1911d4000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6d20 0x1844ec000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4eb0 0x1844ec000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
4   WebCore                         0x000000018de133b8 0x18dd14000 + 1045432
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fe18 0x19126c000 + 15896
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fd70 0x19126c000 + 15728
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d550 0x19126c000 + 5456

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911d5ca0 0x1911d4000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b6d20 0x1844ec000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4eb0 0x1844ec000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844f5dcc 0x1844ec000 + 40396
4   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d75abc 0x183d30000 + 285372
5   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d66278 0x183d30000 + 221816
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fe18 0x19126c000 + 15896
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126fd70 0x19126c000 + 15728
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d550 0x19126c000 + 5456

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911eee74 0x1911d4000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d548 0x19126c000 + 5448

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001911eee74 0x1911d4000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019126d548 0x19126c000 + 5448

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fd881f8
    x4: 0x0000000000002060   x5: 0x000000016fd882b0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000640
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000093fad6f7  x11: 0x0000000000000400
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x000000019119bdcb
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000e814b9a56c6c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000193fc02a0  x21: 0x0000000170124158  x22: 0x0000000170124180  x23: 0x0000000191d2ca90
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000187cb51ea  x26: 0x0000000193fac098  x27: 0x0000000191d44000
   x28: 0x0000000191d44000  fp: 0x000000016fd88230   lr: 0x000000019127116c
    sp: 0x000000016fd88210   pc: 0x00000001911ee58c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100074000 - 0x100097fff Catch52 arm64  <c52fbfc47a653afca4218a9711f9db42> /var/mobile/Applications/FA761024-4026-4EB1-AF58-B6D530C010A1/Catch52.app/Catch52
0x10242c000 - 0x1024b7fff UIKit arm64  <8f9e15954dc13868b7be7cd2ced9b7fb> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit
0x102584000 - 0x102587fff RemoteUIFramework arm64  <2ee7af1d1c8f3ab5ab0b106f4d713553> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/RemoteUIFramework.axbundle/RemoteUIFramework
0x102590000 - 0x102593fff GeoServices arm64  <498751b136b03e3a8f81444e7becdcfb> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle/GeoServices
0x10259c000 - 0x10259ffff GameKitFramework arm64  <7efef6799c7538919aabb5be7ee7f40c> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GameKitFramework.axbundle/GameKitFramework
0x1025a8000 - 0x1025abfff GameCenterUIFramework arm64  <c4d1673493fe3becbaf700e89623f699> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GameCenterUIFramework.axbundle/GameCenterUIFramework
0x1025b8000 - 0x1025bffff AddressBookUIFramework arm64  <9076360d2f0239a6a37643038219589c> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AddressBookUIFramework.axbundle/AddressBookUIFramework
0x1025d4000 - 0x1025d7fff StoreKitFramework arm64  <860c011d84ae3729b35a486a13ee71fe> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitFramework.axbundle/StoreKitFramework
0x120024000 - 0x12004bfff dyld arm64  <628da833271c3f9bb8d44c34060f55e0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182f64000 - 0x182f67fff AXSpeechImplementation arm64  <bd8ac0710a783770a58c06323d6daaf4> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AXSpeechImplementation.bundle/AXSpeechImplementation
0x182f68000 - 0x182f6ffff AccessibilitySettingsLoader arm64  <6722ae511d8f3b478f94e11db32c7594> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x18322c000 - 0x18334ffff AVFoundation arm64  <dc692cb5c6ee3424989572559c54e8b5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x183350000 - 0x18337bfff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <62ec9970748835d8a25c0e1c302671af> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x18337c000 - 0x18337ffff Accelerate arm64  <fe3a369c06d23c4fb0c053964eab7e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x18338c000 - 0x18355ffff vImage arm64  <35138843dfb73924908202512ca0e178> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x183560000 - 0x1835fffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <d1836bd233333aadb94d6f848f22251e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x183600000 - 0x183963fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <8c24faa666963e4d905cd73fef3b7324> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x183964000 - 0x1839bbfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f9b2f7b3ea2938bf99adbdf9e4cc159c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1839bc000 - 0x1839dbfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <bd7cb5c078cf3d7bba947c31f3d802ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1839dc000 - 0x1839dffff vecLib arm64  <c29a5c80dbf73db7b35ea6912c01192a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1839e0000 - 0x183a07fff Accounts arm64  <e3e2a24b6b1b33d2809d4f49a00fd853> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x183a0c000 - 0x183a87fff AddressBook arm64  <d001052b680f3b2bbd7b6c96d8f940bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x183a88000 - 0x183bcbfff AddressBookUI arm64  <b86fb6eb881a37d4bcc931a7533d898b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x183be0000 - 0x183d2ffff AudioCodecs arm64  <4338e3f1bfa23076ad6a0f444c6b8d41> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x183d30000 - 0x1840a7fff AudioToolbox arm64  <3302507f40c9336bbe1922a60401b128> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1840a8000 - 0x184247fff CFNetwork arm64  <4ec38ca636863fd98d35625d742545ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x184248000 - 0x1842abfff CoreAudio arm64  <0bce07df49ec33b2bd6f77e60ce18244> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1842ac000 - 0x1842c7fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <e7b48382dbad3a0b83ab85dde10f9a89> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1842c8000 - 0x1844ebfff CoreData arm64  <811c3566ff1f3e7dba868ad962bc8e09> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1844ec000 - 0x184677fff CoreFoundation arm64  <a1136ebc9e303a6cbedb1ce0c439a440> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x184678000 - 0x1847d7fff CoreGraphics arm64  <bc6469e30387387f93c0d187bda24708> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1847dc000 - 0x184827fff libCGFreetype.A.dylib arm64  <1e8883afb3c334f3bb68a34bd7f2b9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x18482c000 - 0x184837fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <e99b2dd1a3223783b1fc70926db57680> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x184a2c000 - 0x184a4bfff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <4ecdb92170223a4f8aaf3a77cf2c99ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x184a4c000 - 0x184b43fff CoreImage arm64  <85a9a28611543d73ae2c66c6225bbca2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x184b44000 - 0x184b9bfff CoreLocation arm64  <26ef0bff69233a8ca7d3c54c51763711> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x184bd8000 - 0x184c6ffff CoreMedia arm64  <1824c85fc81c30349dd25ed9d29bb38a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x184c70000 - 0x184d27fff CoreMotion arm64  <f1a251d274733f418c7a522461672cd8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x184d28000 - 0x184d97fff CoreTelephony arm64  <c521e7263fda379e852a736f9312323d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x184d98000 - 0x184e53fff CoreText arm64  <2e61eb4412ee3c06b3f031f85973b49d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x184e54000 - 0x184e6bfff CoreVideo arm64  <305841cbb8013a65accac4dd231c1354> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x185080000 - 0x1852bffff Foundation arm64  <372b2c4e355d3f8eb804a10eedd64147> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1852c0000 - 0x1852ebfff GLKit arm64  <1bf7b85401a6391082e45484bc1e76da> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
0x185328000 - 0x1853b7fff GameCenterFoundation arm64  <397a8e729a1338c0a96c56304d1a1ee5> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Frameworks/GameCenterFoundation.framework/GameCenterFoundation
0x1853b8000 - 0x1854dbfff GameCenterUI arm64  <ff411c78ae953cf1bfb8627936d2f91d> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Frameworks/GameCenterUI.framework/GameCenterUI
0x1854dc000 - 0x1854ebfff LegacyGameKit arm64  <e14bed6320413c7ba35df7a5db67abc4> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Frameworks/LegacyGameKit.framework/LegacyGameKit
0x1854ec000 - 0x1854effff GameKit arm64  <3b282e206101379f8c2511361d533411> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/GameKit
0x1854f0000 - 0x18555ffff IOKit arm64  <2b074686d7a33f55a22dbe4a1c110983> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x185560000 - 0x1857c3fff ImageIO arm64  <cfd70969e3213716b06a24458540d2a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1857c4000 - 0x185ad7fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <d67216a7191c3dce94d45211ba4220d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x185b9c000 - 0x185ba3fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <3c82a5730bdf3b6cad5b4c4b130537b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x185df4000 - 0x18618bfff MediaToolbox arm64  <fbb86dca9af63672a3e396f75296bec8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x186250000 - 0x1862cbfff MobileCoreServices arm64  <9c9a3a25ee153b40a98c57260afdb87b> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x186f40000 - 0x186f4bfff OpenGLES arm64  <9991bb08084d3a619f516803b53270e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x186f50000 - 0x186f53fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <630f687df00530b7923e05f809f34393> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x186f58000 - 0x186f5ffff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <84c6d0e5cda3363c9f3899aafad06708> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x186f60000 - 0x186f6bfff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <243c0a12fa733ea887431fe48afd9e30> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x186f6c000 - 0x186fb7fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <4ffb900f9bb63098b87f94613cf5a980> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x18719c000 - 0x187317fff QuartzCore arm64  <b164c2e185f33277a862a0a0d31d1688> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18737c000 - 0x1873d3fff Security arm64  <16749a42d40a3aa29b4ff61730dd0233> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x187528000 - 0x18753ffff StoreKit arm64  <5566bfd8968030749490c68cc455c4a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x187540000 - 0x1875a7fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <02d25abf132f3308b8a0d4b86adf4e72> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1875ac000 - 0x187de3fff UIKit arm64  <3e84ffc9d56a390da5c15c4a0f4bb743> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x187de4000 - 0x187e3ffff VideoToolbox arm64  <9bb1901c1eb737cca6c86d9b8380b47c> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18816c000 - 0x188177fff AOSNotification arm64  <66acd0f108093361ae4d4776bd9b6ade> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x1881a4000 - 0x1881cbfff AXRuntime arm64  <203e3e54a9983ee2bf9d8a9a440a72c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXRuntime.framework/AXRuntime
0x1881e8000 - 0x18823ffff AccessibilityUtilities arm64  <53e96dd7e43c3fc4940703ed06bf147c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
0x1882cc000 - 0x1882d3fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <70612602bac139afb727273c163d4b04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x188a28000 - 0x188a73fff AppSupport arm64  <c29c476da1de384285f4fe12530303f2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x188a74000 - 0x188ab7fff AppleAccount arm64  <9c9a7a0225783d3b8e68f7e9fd05bc8a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x188ab8000 - 0x188abffff AppleAccountUI arm64  <1e2391141ba93597bde3bc4f7c642eb7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccountUI.framework/AppleAccountUI
0x188b7c000 - 0x188b8ffff ApplePushService arm64  <d65b51edaade300cb3c562e8fcd74385> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x188b90000 - 0x188b9bfff AppleSRP arm64  <48092ad0ed5737ceb5796f5dfaf22a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x188ba4000 - 0x188bb3fff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <0a43b3d5d80137b4bf8bc0773bd41c04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x188c0c000 - 0x188c13fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <313c8a34f6903532bac6527133952e03> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x188c14000 - 0x188c43fff BackBoardServices arm64  <e51f485d712c3d4cb89f28d82e421d52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x188c64000 - 0x188c6bfff BluetoothManager arm64  <340e4bd2217038c4a19e22d80533a648> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x188c6c000 - 0x188c9bfff Bom arm64  <5ed907690adf3ca3bbc193dd20c2ea40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x188d5c000 - 0x188d67fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <a550e527f7c43d59b77218c2a573192e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x188d68000 - 0x188e7bfff Celestial arm64  <2dd7730e95173c94b9abe140b208ce71> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x188e8c000 - 0x188e93fff CertUI arm64  <264496ce74983ee8915df236df3d8365> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x188ff8000 - 0x189007fff CommonUtilities arm64  <7edf50583ddc3f2f95208fc2988fec3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x189008000 - 0x18900ffff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <9782939d0cc03a7c80fc6bc768bd1228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x1890b8000 - 0x1890bbfff ConstantClasses arm64  <bd2c9b5aa4093ca28a37adde17ea3377> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x189104000 - 0x189107fff CoreAUC arm64  <9e53d18a83393dea8f7b579fac68f96c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x189308000 - 0x1893b7fff CorePDF arm64  <dbb461ba157a36a1b278bf94050753a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x189424000 - 0x18944bfff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <bf3625657c283d249fd9214e22f58e2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x18944c000 - 0x18944ffff CoreSurface arm64  <694f231ebc7d36b98b29a9d4739d2a89> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x189450000 - 0x1894c3fff CoreSymbolication arm64  <181693f430d43291adc86d52a5f4dcd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/CoreSymbolication
0x189514000 - 0x18957ffff CoreUI arm64  <d9f5377e07603e489cfd4e2a255e2a91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x189580000 - 0x1895e3fff CoreUtils arm64  <14400b3d4e653812b7adafd309b34789> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x1895e4000 - 0x1895ebfff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <ea2c2608b0ef3d81b77579705962b2b7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x189804000 - 0x18981ffff DataAccessExpress arm64  <3c67e1c506e1377f9cdcaa9e53a1f741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18982c000 - 0x189847fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <f4818a2682a839ed970c14f8a655e0d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x189868000 - 0x18986ffff DataMigration arm64  <c837b70cc0d13310b8f0b268bef13456> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x189878000 - 0x18987bfff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <f85831ad8802333681f41ce9328996c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18987c000 - 0x18989ffff DictionaryServices arm64  <edc87944e473327a90211e41004a6fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x1898c4000 - 0x1898e7fff EAP8021X arm64  <fb9da5e6cc6735d680e1a858a74ba6a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x1898f0000 - 0x1898fffff ExFAT arm64  <c68dc8ccc1d835eca019dbc4a664b9a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExFAT.framework/ExFAT
0x189918000 - 0x189947fff FTServices arm64  <d4faaed725763d71a69663146c186515> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x189948000 - 0x189d6bfff FaceCore arm64  <bda66fcd68093766bc529a79b8e88fff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x189db8000 - 0x189ef7fff AVConference arm64  <6eb8d310bccc3b398d0031aac6cf2415> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
0x189f04000 - 0x189f2bfff ICE arm64  <01666979d50b346ba128ba850d864f47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/ICE.framework/ICE
0x189f2c000 - 0x189f2ffff LegacyHandle arm64  <e762e5d084963083b8b2026abceb04d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/LegacyHandle.framework/LegacyHandle
0x189f30000 - 0x189f3bfff SimpleKeyExchange arm64  <fb2dae702b8b3f75ae97be717a65407d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/SimpleKeyExchange.framework/SimpleKeyExchange
0x189f3c000 - 0x189f53fff ViceroyTrace arm64  <791fec86ab67391ea7729559635e54f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace
0x189f54000 - 0x189f57fff snatmap arm64  <16eed2c194b430a68ee5fdc51c9f2fb7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/Frameworks/snatmap.framework/snatmap
0x189f58000 - 0x189fdffff GameKitServices arm64  <da5ef2ebaf63300daeed709ed3d4e15f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x189ff0000 - 0x18a1cffff GeoServices arm64  <0bedb4e259563344a9700d5db0c1c2a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x18a1d0000 - 0x18a1ebfff GraphicsServices arm64  <84133b2c6b5a33ef851b17e9eb0e8c35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18a468000 - 0x18a47bfff IDSFoundation arm64  <9f2d8e3bda7f35bcafc766a2b66832d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x18a618000 - 0x18a67ffff IMFoundation arm64  <d42e252d146034f7b71df0ff56ebb560> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x18a68c000 - 0x18a697fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <29c30af4b4ec3d6fa503e729133af73d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x18a698000 - 0x18a69ffff IOSurface arm64  <7f23673517f3359d8996474d139d1229> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18a7cc000 - 0x18a7dbfff MailServices arm64  <74de9bc220e03709a527ab94f8b49162> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x18a81c000 - 0x18a8affff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <9ae490a6102b3ed594dd19a889a9452c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x18a8b0000 - 0x18a8b3fff Marco arm64  <d795409f187832d69ad609a5a7d3d1b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x18a8b4000 - 0x18a93bfff MediaControlSender arm64  <efa9bf53b7ea3c53a9af712dd66be2fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x18a984000 - 0x18a993fff MediaRemote arm64  <d4c667d25a153e87b0bda5c311232091> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x18ab28000 - 0x18ab2bfff MessageSupport arm64  <93b9437cfa193c3489cc3c6fb1fa6789> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x18ab38000 - 0x18ab47fff MobileAsset arm64  <1a818ccb99253fc0b91d7662d701b70a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
```

...
   I was unable to post the entire crash log because of size. I hope this will help find the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your app crashing? Provide details about the crash.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the people testing the app that have it closing not crashing. I do not have any devices with IOS 7.1.2 so I can't personally test it. The app does not crash or close using IOS 8 or above.

Comment: However it always closes when the [self presentViewController is executed.

Comment: You need to get the crash log from the other user's device.

Comment: How can I do that since I have no contact with them? The devices are iPhones. Should they sync them with iTunes and look for the crash reports? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Most of my beta testers are blind users. The info I found seems to indicate that the crash reports will be located in specific directories depending on whether they were synced on Mac or Windows. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered several items that I did not know. First I downloaded the IOS 7.1 simulator and use it to duplicate the crash in xcode. Which led to the second discovery of some bad code in the viewDidLoad method. I corrected it and all is now well. Thanks so much for your help and guidance.